# Call web2py jsonrpc service using jquery

Tags: jquery, web2py

I am trying to make ajax jsonrpc call to my web service using jQuery as given below:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnNext,#btnPrevious").click(function() {
        var req = {
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "nextprevexample",
            id: (new Date).getTime()
        };
        req.res = {
            name: 'aajas'
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/adv01/default/call/jsonrpc",
            data: JSON.stringify(req),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(rpcRes) {
                alert(rpcRes.result);
                $("#lblexample").text(rpcRes.result[1]);
                $("#txtexamplereviewed").val(rpcRes.result[1]);
            },
            error: function(err, status, thrown) {
                alert(thrown); //alert(status);alert(thrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I am trying to access it in my web2py web service. The code of web service is as follows:

```
@service.json   
@service.jsonrpc    
def nextprevexample():    
    print request.post_vars
    exampleid,exampletext=getcorrespondingexample()
    return exampleid,exampletext
```

But the problem is I don't get anything in post_vars.

I tried to search entire request object to find any property which would give me posted data but didn't find one.

Please let me know if I have doing anything wrong over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP posted this in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/nwcuxmsULdg) too, with the following result:

*Thanks Anthony. I checked it and it was throwing error as my web service definition was wrong. Also, my jQuery code was incorrect. I fixed both and it started working. Here I am posting my code if it could help anybody in future for reference.*

*jquery:*

```
function nextprevajaxcall(nextprevindicator)

{
  var req = {jsonrpc:"2.0", method: "nextprevexample",id:(new Date).getTime()};     
  req.params=[nextprevindicator];

  $.ajax({        
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/adv01/default/call/jsonrpc",
    data: JSON.stringify(req),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(rpcRes) {            
        //alert(JSON.stringify(rpcRes));

        $("#lblexample").text(rpcRes.result[1]);
        $("#txtexamplereviewed").val(rpcRes.result[1]);
    },
    error: function(err, status, thrown) {          
      alert(thrown);//alert(status);alert(thrown);
    }  
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#btnNext").click(function(){        
    nextprevajaxcall(1);
    return false;
  });
  $("#btnPrevious").click(function(){        
    nextprevajaxcall(0);
    return false;
  });
});
```

*web2py controller:*

```
@service.json   
@service.jsonrpc    
def nextprevexample(nextprevindicator):
    #print nextprevindicator    
    exampleid,exampletext=getcorrespondingexample(nextprevindicator)    
    return exampleid,exampletext
```

*Please notice that whatever we send in request.params of jquery code gets posted as parameters to web2py jsonrpc web service.*